# How to send JSON body in GET request golang?

Tags: http, go, get, payload

There is no "body" field in [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Get) for http.Client.Get

Comment: GET and DELETE requests do not have body. If you need to send a body, use PUT, POST, PATCH

Comment: @Flimzy, I'm inclined to think the linked answer, while definitely useful, does not answer the essense of the question: broken services (usually software developed in house) do exist, and I'd not be too surprised to find out the OP really needs to send a body in a GET request because it's what their target service _wants._ I would reopen the question.

Comment: @kostix: Fair point.

Comment: Though, if the problem is that there's an in-house server using broken standards, then creating an in-house client using broken standards means there are now two problems.  Fixing the server would be the better long-term approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sending a body with a GET request is not supported by HTTP. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body) for full details.  But if you really want to do this, even though you know it's wrong, you can do it this way:

```golang
iKnowThisBodyShouldBeIgnored := strings.NewReader("text that won't mean anything")
req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "http://example.com/foo", iKnowThisBodyShouldBeIgnored)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Do not send body in a GET request: [an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061).

   RFC 7231 [says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) the following:

   > A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
   > sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
   > implementations to reject the request.
2. If you must, do not use `net/http.Get` as it's just a convenience function.
   Instead, go one level deeper and construct a proper [`http.Request`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) which then perform by calling the [`Do`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Do) method on an instance of [`http.Client`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client) (the [`http.DefaultClient`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#DefaultClient) should be just fine).